# Why does $[L_i,\textbf{L}^2]=0$ and $[L_i,H]=0$ imply that $[\textbf{L}^2,H]=0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

For a particle in a central potential, the orbital angular momentum magnitude operator $\textbf{L}^2$  commutes with the Hamiltonian operator $H$, i.e. $$[\textbf{L}^2,H]=0.$$

I read that one way to prove this is to first note that $$[L_i,\textbf{L}^2]=0,$$ where $L_i$ is the orbital angular momentum component operator. Furthermore, since $L_i$ commutes with $H$, i.e. $$[L_i,H]=0,$$ so does $\textbf{L}^2$.

Why does $[L_i,\textbf{L}^2]=0$ and $[L_i,H]=0$ imply that $[\textbf{L}^2,H]=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[\textbf{L}^2,H] = [\sum_i L_i^2,H] = \sum_i [L_i^2,H].$

If $[L_i,H]=0$, then so that $[f(L_i),H]=0$  where $f$ is a function of $L_i$, and hence $[L_i^2,H]=0$.

Hence,
$$ \sum_i [L_i^2,H] = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad [\textbf{L}^2,H] = 0.$$

Comment: I think that using the identity $[A B, C]]=A[B,C] + [A,C]B$ is more in line with what they expected here, since that would be used to actually prove that the Hamilton commutes with any function of the angular momentum.

Answer (score 4):

First, We have formula
$$[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B.$$
Since $L_i$ commutes with $H$, we can identify $[L_i^2,H]=0$ below
$$
\begin{split}
   [L_i^2,H] &= L_i[L_i,H]+[L_i,H]L_i\\
             &=0.
\end{split}
$$
Then we have
$$
[L^2,H]=\sum[L_i^2,H]=0
$$
because of $L^2=\sum L_i^2$.

I think the condition $[L_i,L^2]$ don't work for this question, because they always true for angular momentum.